# error when close connection using mysqli on PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new in PHP development, I get a warning like this when making email confirmation registration:

> Registration success, please login using your data
>
> Warning: mysqli::close(): Couldn't fetch
> mysqli in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Twitter/security/access.php on
> line 42

here is the simplified code of access.php

```
class access {

    public $host = null;
    public $username = null;
    public $password = null;
    public $dbname = null;
    public $conn = null;
    public $result = null;

    function __construct($xhost,$xusername,$xpassword,$xdbname) {
        $this->host = $xhost;
        $this->username = $xusername;
        $this->password = $xpassword;
        $this->dbname = $xdbname;
    }


    // connection to database
    function connect() {
        $this->conn = new mysqli($this->host,$this->username,$this->password,$this->dbname);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Connection to database failed: ".mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        // support all languages
        $this->conn->set_charset("utf8");
    }


    public function disconnect() {

        if ($this->conn != null) {
            $this->conn->close();
        }

    }



    //saving token to the database 
    function saveTokens ($table, $id, $token) {

        $query = "INSERT INTO $table SET id=?, token=?";
        $statement = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        if (!$statement) {
            throw new Exception($statement->error);
        }

        $statement-> bind_param('is',$id,$token);
        $returnValue = $statement ->execute();

        return $returnValue;
    }


    // get userID from given Token 
    function getIDFromToken($table,$token) {

        $returnValue = [];

        $query = "SELECT id FROM $table WHERE token='$token'";
        $result = $this->conn->query($query);


        if ($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)) {

            $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            if (!empty($row)) {
                $returnValue = $row;
            }
        }

        return $returnValue;
    }



    function updateEmailConfirmationStatus($status,$id) {

        $query = "UPDATE users SET emailConfirmed =? WHERE id=?";

        $statement = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        if (!$statement) {
            throw new Exception($statement->error);
        }

        $statement-> bind_param('ii',$status,$id);
        $returnValue = $statement ->execute();

        return $returnValue;

    }

    // delete token when ID is available
    function deleteToken($table,$token) {

        $query = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE token =?";

        $statement = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        if (!$statement) {
            throw new Exception($statement->error);
        }

        $statement-> bind_param('s',$token);
        $returnValue = $statement ->execute();

        return $returnValue;


    }



}
```

and I use access.php in confirmationlink.php
here is the code on confirmationlink.php

```
<?php 
require_once("../security/access.php");


if (empty($_GET["token"])) {
    echo "Please follow as per the procedure";
    return;
} 

$token = htmlentities($_GET["token"]);
    
// making connection to the database
$file = parse_ini_file("../../../../twitter.ini");
$dbhost = trim($file["host"]);
$dbusername = trim($file["username"]);
$dbpassword = trim($file["password"]);
$dbname = trim($file["dbname"]);

$access = new access($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);
$access->connect();

// get ID from database as per the Token created
$info = $access->GetIDFromToken("emailTokens",$token);
$id = $info["id"];

// change emailConfirmed status to 1 if user has pressed confirmation link
$result = $access -> updateEmailConfirmationStatus(1,$id);

// menghapus token apabila ID sudah terkonfirmasi ada di database
if ($result) {
    $access ->deleteToken("emailTokens",$token);
    echo "Registration success, please login using your data";
}

// close the connection
$access -> disconnect();
```

I get the error only on the last line of confirmationlink.php file. the database has been changed successfully on MySQL as I want. I also use `disconnect` method on other PHP file but i have no issue. but somehow I got the issue now

what went wrong in here ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You'll be better off using construct function instead of connect()

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your statements before you return the result in each of the functions:

```
$statement->close();
```